# Symmetric tensor eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, tensors, diagonalization

I'm trying to complete a question on symmetric rank 2 tensors in 3D. So far I have shown that the eigenvalues (and their multiplicities) of $T_{ij}$ (more strictly of the 3x3 matrix with entries given by $T_{ij}$ i suppose but i will abuse the terminology here) is independent of coordinate frame. I'm okay up to here.

The question then asks us to show that, given $T_{ij}$ has eigenvalues $\lambda,\lambda,\mu$ that we can write $$T_{ij}=\alpha\delta_{ij}+\beta n_in_j$$ where $n$ is a unit vector.

My attempt:

$T_{ij}$ is real and symmetric and hence diagonalisable by an orthogonal matrix, so $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda&0&0 \\ 0&\lambda&0 \\ 0&0&\mu \\ \end{pmatrix} = P^TTP$ where P is the matrix formed by placing the orthonormal vectors **a**,**b**,**c** in the columns of P.
Rearranging for $T_{ij}$ and expanding out the summation we find
$$T_{ij}=\lambda a_i a_j+\lambda b_i b_j + \mu c_i c_j$$
But I fail to see how this agrees with the given form? I suppose i could let $\alpha = 0$, $\beta = 2\lambda+\mu$ and $n_i n_j = \frac{\lambda a_i a_j+\lambda b_i b_j + \mu c_i c_j}{2\lambda + \mu}$ but i doubt this is what the question was looking for seeing as i'm completely ignoring the delta part.
So where have i gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation of $T_{ij}$ is incorrect. You should find $T_{11} = \lambda a_1^2 + \lambda a_2^2 + \mu a_3^2$ for instance. I have no idea how you arrived to your formula.

This being said, rather than doing a brute-force computation, you should rather observe that the formula you want to prove amounts to $T=\alpha I_3 + \beta N$ where $N$ is the orthogonal projection on the unit vector $n$. Then observe that 
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \mu \end{pmatrix} = \lambda I_3 + \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \mu-\lambda \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I don't think my computation of $T_{ij}$ is incorrect, and we should find e.g. $T_{11}=\lambda a_1^2 + \lambda b_1^2 +\mu c_1^2$ by either direct expansion of the matrices or suffix notation and summation convention, but regardless your alternative method is much appreciated

Comment: Ah, my bad, I had written $T=P^T D P$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix and not $D=P^TTP$ as you did, so of course the formulas are different. (Just for future reference, it is much more convenient to express your matrix in terms of the diagonal one and not the converse.)